# Check field change in own edit form

Tags: 2010, javascript

We have a list with 3 different textfields (textfield 1, textfield 2, textfield 3) and 3 different datafields (datafield 1, datafield 2, datadiels 3).
We work with a own edit-form. 
Now i want to add a javascript which checks if one or more of this 6 fields will be changed before saving the edits.
I thought about a presaveaction(), but the only presaveaction() i'd have ever use is to check that a field isn't blank.

```
var picker = document.getElementById("[FIELD-ID]")

        if (picker.value == "") 

             {

                     alert('Field can't be blank');

                     return false;

                    }

                    else 

                    {

alert('You saved your edit successfully');

return true;
```

Has somebody an idea how I can change the code to look if the there is a field change?

Answer (score 0):

easiest way can be..at the background, immediately after page load, save data from these fields in 6 different variables. Now once user clicks on save button, use presaveaction (As u already mentioned) and compare them with current value from the fields and take necessary action.

let me know, if this is not clear.

More proof full way will be , having current item ID and then get values from sharepoint list and compare them on presaveaction.

Comment: I tested it with a script which doesn't work. If i change a value,nothing happens. I can't save the changes, the form will be still open. No alert, nothing. 

HERE IS THE CODE:
var prev_value = "";
function store()
{
 pre_val = document.getElementById("[Field-ID").value

}
function PreSaveAction()
{
 var cur_val = document.getEleme
ntById("Field-ID").value 

 if(cur_val != pre_val) alert
("Value changed");

 else alert("Value not changed");
}

I don't get what should be wrong with the code. :o(

Comment: checked your short code, are you returning true or false?any way you can share exact code? once i had same issue, that time problem was with positioning of saveaction function. i put that in additionalpageHead contentholder and it had started working.

Comment: Here i created a new code without presave action. I son't know how I can share my code as in this way:
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("ctl00_m_g_4db567a6_c7ce_4907_bla_bla_bla");
    var defaultVal = x.defaultValue;
    var currentVal = x.value;
    var password;
    var pass1="test";
    
    if (defaultVal == currentVal) {
        password=prompt('Please enter your password to view this page!',' ');
    } 
if (password==pass1){
  alert('Password Correct!');}

else {alert("Value not changed");
    }
}
</script>

Comment: Can try putting debugger in browser? and put just simple alert in preSaveaction(), once you start getting an alert, then put your business logic